# Error in parsing data NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am working in a simple android application and i am trying to retrieve data from mysql database on localhost. Below is the code that i have written so far.The error that i am getting is the following:

```
Error in parsing data java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I used the debugger to check if the retrieved data is correct. And it is. The retrieved data is : `[{"CropID":"1","CropName":"Corn"},{"CropID":"2","CropName":"Wheat"}]`

What i am getting that error?

```
package com.testexternaldatabase;    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView resultView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            System.out.println("*** My thread is now configured to allow connection");
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);  
        getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_connect/getCrops.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Could not connect to the database");
        } 

        //convert response to string

        try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result " + e.toString());

        } 

        //parse json data

        try {
            String s = "";          

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);  
            int id = 0;
            String name = null;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(json != null){
                    id = json.getInt("CropID");

                    name = json.getString("CropName");

                }
                s = s + "Crop ID: " + id + "\n" + "Crop Name: " + name + "\n\n";
            }
            resultView.setText(s);

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

LOG CAT

[image: this]

Comment: At which line does the `Exception` occur?

Comment: and the stacktrace? You forcefully hide a usefull stacktrace in your log statements... Have fun debugging :-)

Comment: You need to a use asynctask or a thread. no need for strictmode

Comment: Debug it, if json is null. name could just get null and parse json could fail when use it.

Comment: @fpanizza i used the debugger and `id` and `name` are not null

Comment: @Raghunandan i am new to android. i will follow your suggestion and use asyntask as soon as i get clear on how to use it.

Comment: @NiekHaarman when i debugged the application, i checked if the id and the name are correctly retrieved. And there are correct. The line that is getting the error is last the catch clause.

Comment: Please use your debugger to put a breakpoint on the line inside the catch clause.  When execution arrives, inspect the exception itself and look at its stack trace.  It will show you the line number of the line that actually *threw* the exception.  Can you please tell us what line this is?  Knowing the line that *caught* the exception is not terribly useful.

Comment: @DavidWallace the line that throws the exception is `resultView.setText(s);`

Comment: OK, that tells us that `resultView` is null at that point.  So the next step in your investigation would be to debug inside the `onCreate` method, to see why `resultView` is not being set.

Comment: @DavidWallace Problem solved! can you submit an answer to accept it?

Comment: No, because I still don't know exactly what the problem was.  Maybe you could post the solution, and I'll upvote it :-)